# wsimport JAXB classes for enumerations

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd, wsdl, wsimport

I've got a WSDL with embedded Schema in it that includes some `simpleType` restrictions with enumerations:

```
<element name="employeeId">
    <simpleType>
        <restriction base="string">
            <maxLength value="2"/>
            <enumeration value="EL"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
</element>
```

(Yes, I know that example has only a single enumeration value.)
In some earlier, vendor-specific tooling, these were generating Java enums, but in my current wsimport (JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01) they are not.

I've done a lot of searching, which finds many discussions on custom mappings. I'm probably not willing to manually map individual classes & values, so I was trying to find some working syntax to do this globally.

However, much of my reading seems to indicate the default should be to create these enums:
https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_2_2_9-Defining-an-Enumeration.html#Defining%20an%20Enumeration

That you have to explicitly disable them if you don't want them. e.g. https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.5-5/docs/ch03.html#compiling-xml-schema-avoid-strong-databinding

Should that be correct? If so, any ideas why it's not happening?

Additional question, should enum generation occur with `xsd:token` as well, or only with `xsd:string`?

Comment: Having a similar issue, wouldn't mind this question getting some TLC.

Comment: I'm having the same problem! Apache XMLBeans works as expected (enums are generated) but JAX-WS 2 no! See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235074/no-enums-generated-by-jax-ws-ri-2-2-1-for-amazon-ecs-wsdl-file

Comment: Strangely, I *think* some of my enumerations are generating enums, but not this one. Haven't yet tried to see what's different between them. No custom settings or mappings in either case.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no global or general solution or setting for this. You need a binding customization file.
Having a separate schema, files similar to this work for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           jaxb:version="1.0">
   <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="your_schema_name.xsd" node="/xs:schema">

   <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='employeeId']/xs:simpleType">
     <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass name="employeeId" />
   </jaxb:bindings>

   </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

When running wsimport, use the -b switch to make it use your binding customization (wsimport -b filename ...).

If you have the schema embedded in the wsdl, try this binding customization:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxws:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
           jaxb:version="2.0"
           wsdlLocation="your_wsdl_name.wsdl">

   <jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='employeeId']/xs:simpleType">
     <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass name="someElement" />
   </jaxws:bindings>

</jaxws:bindings>
```

I tried this also as an external file (wsimport -b filename.xjb ...).
Note: I had to use jaxws:bindings instead of jaxb:bindings for the XPath resolution to work properly. The jaxb:typesafeEnumClass is still in the jaxb namespace, though.