# Rename WSDL elements with identical names using a JAX-WS binding customization

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I need to create a JAX-WS client for an externally provided WSDL file. The WSDL
file has been generated via code-first approach using *Apache CXF* using JAX-WS.
The problem I ran into is related to inner enum classes with identical names (in
this case the name `EventCause`).

During generation via the `wsimport` tool, the following warning occurs (sadly in German):

```
src-resolve: Name 'ns1:eventCause' kann nicht als 'type definition'-Komponente aufgelöst werden.
  Zeile [n] von file:/D:/MyService.wsdl#types?schema1
src-resolve: Name 'ns2:eventCause' kann nicht als 'type definition'-Komponente aufgelöst werden.
  Zeile [n] von file:/D:/MyService.wsdl#types?schema1
```

I tried to create a bindings configuration file to rename the `eventCause`
elements defined in the WSDL, but I am unable to make it work.

The relevant parts of the WSDL file `MyService.wsdl` are provided below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="MyService"
                  targetNamespace="https://service.example.org/my/info"
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                  xmlns:tns="https://service.example.org/my/info"
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
  <wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:ns1="org.example.core.MyNotification"
           xmlns:ns2="org.example.core.MyRequest"
           xmlns:tns="https://service.example.org/my/info"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="unqualified"
           targetNamespace="https://service.example.org/my/info">
  <xs:import namespace="org.example.core.MyNotification"/>
  <xs:import namespace="org.example.core.MyRequest"/>

  <!-- Shortened... -->

  <xs:complexType name="myNotification">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="tns:fooEvent">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="eventCause" type="ns1:eventCause"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <!-- Shortened... -->

  <xs:complexType name="myRequest">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="tns:fooEvent">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="eventCause" type="ns2:eventCause"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <!-- Shortened... -->

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="org.example.core.MyRequest" version="1.0">

  <xs:simpleType name="eventCause">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="FOO"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="BAR"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="org.example.core.MyNotification" version="1.0">

  <xs:simpleType name="eventCause">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="FOO"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="BAR"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="BAZ"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <!-- Shortened... -->

</wsdl:definitions>
```

**So my question are:**

1. What do I have to specify in the JAX-WS bindings file to rename the two `eventCause` elements specified in the WSDL?
2. Is the above possible at all with the warnings?
3. Do the warnings need to be fixed first? If so, how-to fix the warning?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. A JAX-WS binding file has to be used with `wsimport` (e.g. `bindings.xjb`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxws:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
                xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb
                                    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
                jaxb:version="2.1">
  <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='eventCause']/xs:simpleType">
    <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass name="EventCause" />
  </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

The problem is related to [No enums generated by jax-ws ri 2.2.1 for amazon ecs wsdl file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235074/no-enums-generated-by-jax-ws-ri-2-2-1-for-amazon-ecs-wsdl-file).